# Regex: How to match a range of characters except another range

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex filter to satisfy:
1) The 1st character should be a lower-case letter or a number
2) The rest of the characters should be a single character between index 32 and 126
3) However, none of the characters should be upper case letters or `_`

My current regex is:
`^[a-z0-9][ -~]*$`

This solves 1) and 2) above - but I struggle to include 3) above in the right way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to add a [negative lookahead](https://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1) for what you don't want.

```
^[a-z0-9](?!.*[A-Z_])[ -~]*$
```

But it's also possible to just split up the ranges, based on the [ascii-table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
^[a-z0-9][ -@\[-^`-~]*$
```

It's just a bit less easy to understand at a first glance.